# Create the [nats] tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-request

I asked this question on Stack Overflow: [NATS persistent message Java Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420689/nats-persistent-message-java-client). This question regards the Java client for the [NATS Streaming Server](http://nats.io/documentation/streaming/nats-streaming-quickstart/). I wanted to tag it as [nats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nats). There does not exist a [nats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nats) tag, yet.

---

It looks like the tag [nat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nat) already exists, and that is why I can't create it myself.

Comment: hah, good point. I didn't realize that I could. When I tried to type it in, it said, raise a question on meta. So, I did

Comment: ok, just tried again. Evidently the tag `nat` already exists. But, that's an entirely different enchilada.

Comment: you can't add a "plural" tag.  The system things "nats" is just the plural version of "nat".  May I suggest something like [tag:nats-streaming]?  That should differentiate it from nat and make it less ambiguous

Comment: Ok. I tagged it `nats-streaming-server`. maybe `natsen` could be a synonym.  :)

Comment: @Kirby since you created the tag, you should take the time to create a Tag Wiki and excerpt so people know what the tag means

Comment: @psubsee2003, done

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't create it is the system specifically blocks "plural" versions of tags if the non-plural version already exists.

Since you can't create [nats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nats) due to the existing (and completely unrelated) [nat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nat) tag, I'm going to suggest you create a more descriptive tag, such as [nats-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nats-streaming).

This will work around the current issue, but will also make the tag a lot less ambiguous as it is immediately clear from the name that it is referring to the NATS Streaming Server, rather than NAT or some plural version of that tag